# Wallaby with headless Chrome crashes

Tags: debian, elixir, google-chrome-headless, ex-unit, wallaby

I am developing an application based on Elixir and Phoenix which also uses the Wallaby application for HTTP based testing in a headless Chrome browser.

Now recently I receive a rather unwieldy error message when executing my ExUnit tests:

```
** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value:
    {:error, {:wallaby, {:bad_return, 
      {{Wallaby, :start, [:normal, []]},
      {:EXIT,
        {%Protocol.UndefinedError{description: "", protocol: Enumerable, value: nil},
        [{Enumerable, :impl_for!, 1, [file: '/root/deb/elixir_1.8.0-1/lib/elixir/lib/enum.ex', line: 1]},
         {Enumerable, :slice, 1, [file: '/root/deb/elixir_1.8.0-1/lib/elixir/lib/enum.ex', line: 193]},
         {Enum, :backwards_compatible_slice, 1, [file: 'lib/enum.ex', line: 2871]},
         {Enum, :slice_any, 3, [file: 'lib/enum.ex', line: 3075]},
         {Enum, :at, 3, [file: 'lib/enum.ex', line: 381]},
         {Wallaby.Experimental.Chrome, :validate, 0, [file: 'lib/wallaby/experimental/chrome.ex', line: 36]},
         {Wallaby, :start, 2, [file: 'lib/wallaby.ex', line: 27]},
         {:application_master, :start_it_old, 4, [file: 'application_master.erl', line: 277]}]}}}}}}

test/test_helper.exs:4: (file)
(elixir) lib/code.ex:767: Code.require_file/2
(elixir) lib/enum.ex:769: Enum."-each/2-lists^foreach/1-0-"/2
(elixir) lib/enum.ex:769: Enum.each/2
```

I am running a Debian GNU/Linux 9 "Stretch" and installed Elixir as a `.deb` package with version 1.8.0-1 from `binaries.erlang-solutions.com`. Wallaby is locked to `{:wallaby, "~> 0.21.0"}`.

Ideas on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `v0.21.0` which is the latest of _Wallaby_ has different code in [`chrome.ex:36`](https://github.com/keathley/wallaby/blob/v0.21.0/lib/wallaby/experimental/chrome.ex#L36). Start with updating _Wallaby_.

Comment: Sadly, I'm already running `{:wallaby, "~> 0.21.0"}`.

Comment: Ah, indeed, I misread the code. Then the only option would be to clone, debug, fix, and provide a PR. Or roll back to Elixir 1.7 :)

Comment: I now downgraded Elixir and found out that the error still persists in Elixir 1.7.4. So it is not as formerly suspected a problem with Elixir 1.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by Wallaby 0.21.0 not being able to handle a ChromeDriver version higher than 2.x, but ChromeDriver versions as high as 71.x are already around.

This has been fixed by [this pull request](https://github.com/keathley/wallaby/pull/403), which has been merged into Wallaby `master` but doesn't seem to be released yet.